# How can I access the log via a php script?

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, php

I have a statistics-file on my apache server on

```
/var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log
```

I tried using

```
echo system('cat /var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log');
```

in a php script to access it but I get no output.

```
echo system('dir');
```

gives the expected dir output.

```
cat /var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log
```

using a putty connection and as root works though.

How can I access the log via the php script?

Comment: what does `ls -l /var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log` say?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130771 Jul 24 20:19 /var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log

Comment: This serverfault link might clear things up for you. http://serverfault.com/questions/337022/why-do-files-need-to-be-world-readable-for-apache-to-server-them

Comment: I tried chmod and stuff but each time the access_log is being updated, it rewrites old permission. All I want is output this data.

Comment: @Tim This didn't solve it.

Comment: That was more informative then an actual suggestion. Try this http://serverfault.com/questions/93677/how-to-make-apache-log-files-readable-by-apache?rq=1

Comment: @Tim I did this and now it reads "-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 84280 Jul 25 16:28 access_log". But still permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP process cannot access the file. A CentOS 6 Apache process runs as the user apache.
Example:

```
[root@talara ~]# ps aux | grep httpd
root      2300  0.0  2.7 334744 28020 ?        Ss   Jul10   0:47 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    8354  0.0  2.0 334744 20536 ?        S    Jul21   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    8355  0.0  2.0 334744 20536 ?        S    Jul21   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    8356  0.0  2.0 334744 20536 ?        S    Jul21   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

To test accessing the file as apache I do:

```
[root@talara ~]# su apache
bash-4.1$ cat /var/log/messages
cat: /var/log/messages: Permission denied
bash-4.1$
```

Most ways I know of to allow apache direct access to those files will be frowned upon in one way or another due to the HUGE security hole it opens. However if you think you have security locked down enough, add apache to the sudoers file with no password (see? VERY very bad). Then change your PHP code to something like this:

```
echo system('sudo cat /var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log');
```

Input from the community on a better approach would be welcome.

Comment: not a suitable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you're making system calls to access the file?

If not, you can just use the existing constructs within PHP to get access to the file:

`$log = file_get_contents('/var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log');`

or

`$log = file('/var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/logs/access_log');`

Comment: Yes. No permission using your approach.

Comment: The file is world-readable according to the ls output you pasted earlier - any user or service account should be able to get the contents. What error message do you get when attempting to use file_get_contents?

Comment: @aetimmes as you can see from my su approach above, your method would not have worked on my centos install.

Comment: @aetimmes it might be wr but still I get permission denied

Comment: @Zurechtweiser My bet would be on `open_basedir` restrictions -- those would show up in the error_log.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I changed it in plesk by changing open_basedir to "{WEBSPACEROOT}/:{TMP}/:/var/www/vhosts/test/statistics/" but still: Permission denied.